# How can I convert List<string> to List<myEnumType>?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I failed to convert `List<string>` to `List<myEnumType>`. I don't know why?

```
string Val = it.Current.Value.ToString(); // works well here
List<myEnumType> ValList = new List<myEnumType>(Val.Split(',')); // compile failed
```

Of cause `myEnumType` type defined as string enum type as this,

```
public enum myEnumType
{
    strVal_1,
    strVal_2,
    strVal_3,
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Appreciated for you replies.

Comment: @All, Looks like it is not a stupid question. Thanks for all the rapid replies again. I will practice any of the solutions just tack it as my learning case.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

EDIT: Oops, I missed the C# 2 tag as well. I'll leave the other options available below, but:

In C# 2, you're probably best using [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

```
List<MyEnumType> enumList = stringList.ConvertAll(delegate(string x) {
    return (MyEnumType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumType), x); });
```

or with [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/):

```
List<MyEnumType> enumList = stringList.ConvertAll(delegate(string x) {
    return Enums.ParseName<MyEnumType>(x); });
```

Note that this does assume you really have a `List<string>` to start with, which is correct for your title but not for the body in your question. Fortunately there's an equivalent static [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) method which you'd have to use like this:

```
MyEnumType[] enumArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, delegate (string x) {
    return (MyEnumType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumType), x); });
```

---

**Original answer**

Two options:

- Use Enum.Parse and a cast in a LINQ query:

  ```
  var enumList = stringList
            .Select(x => (MyEnumType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumType), x))
            .ToList();
  ```

or

```
    var enumList = stringList.Select(x => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumType), x))
                             .Cast<MyEnumType>()
                             .ToList();
```

- Use my [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project:

  ```
  var enumList = stringList.Select(x => Enums.ParseName<MyEnumType>(x))
                           .ToList();
  ```

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Looks like I posted a very simple question above. And I get a complex solution beyond my knowledge. I will try it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, can he use this in C# 2.0??

Comment: @Nano HE: See the edit to allow C# 2 code. I would strongly advise you to update to a more recent version of C# if possible :)

Comment: @decyclone: I hadn't spotted the C# 2 tag, but I've updated the answer appropriately.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: +1 for `ConvertAll` + anonymous delegate

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Actually I inserted `C#2.0` after a while when I posted the original version. :-)

Comment: I think in a later version of C# you can do this with your first example:
List<MyEnum> enumList = stringList.ConvertAll(
                        x => (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), x));

Comment: @MikeatKBS: Yes, absolutely - but this question was tagged c#-2.0, hence I've limited myself to that.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 2.0:

```
List<myEnumType> ValList = new List<myEnumType>();
foreach (string x in Val.Split(','))
    ValList.Add((MyEnumType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumType), x));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        List<String> list = new List<String>();

        list.Add("strVal_1");
        list.Add("strVal_2");
        list.Add("strVal_3");

        List<myEnumType> enumList = new List<myEnumType>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            enumList.Add((myEnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnumType), item));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I added an extension method to `IEnumerable<string>` to do this for me. Skeet's answer is good, obviously, but it will throw an exception if the strings aren't valid for the enum (which you may or may not want), and it's a pretty ugly looking line.

```
public static class StringEnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> StringsToEnums<T>( this IEnumerable<string> strs) where T : struct, IConvertible {
        Type t = typeof( T );

        var ret = new List<T>();

        if( t.IsEnum ) {
            T outStr;
            foreach( var str in strs ) {
                if( Enum.TryParse( str, out outStr ) ) {
                    ret.Add( outStr );
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Given this enum:

```
public enum ColorEnum { Blue, Yellow }
```

You can use this like so:

```
var colors = new List<string>() {"Blue","Yellow","Black"};
var colorEnums = colors.StringsToEnums<ColorEnum>();
```

And you'll get a list with just `Blue` and `Yellow`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method and with `Select` do the Work:

```
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static myEnumType GetEnumValue(this string input)
    {
        if (input == myEnumType.strVal_1.ToString())
            return myEnumType.strVal_1;
        return input == myEnumType.strVal_2.ToString() ? myEnumType.strVal_2 : myEnumType.strVal_3;
    }
}

List<myEnumType> ValList = new List<myEnumType>(Val.Split(',').Select(p=>p.GetEnumValue()));
```

I missed c#2.0 tag :)