# How do you convert a List<String> into a List<enum> in java 6?

Tags: java, list, enums

I basically need the Java version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426537/how-can-i-convert-liststring-to-listmyenumtype). I am having a hard time figuring out how to translate that into java.

Say I have an enum of numbers and each one has its own class and method

```
public enum Numbers{
           one,
           two,
           three
           ....
    }
```

I ended up in my program have a list of strings so I need to convert them to a list of enums so I can do something like

```
    for(Number number : listOfNumbers)
        {
        switch (number)
        {
        case one:
            new One();
            One.oneMethod();
            break;
           ...
        }
        }
```

Comment: Just read the linked answer a little further: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4426587/2372767

Comment: You can have very number implement an interface with the method numberMethod. Than you don't need to do the switch statement

Comment: What is class One? Why just call the constructor and not keep the result? What does One.oneMethod() do? Is this supposed to be real Java code?

Comment: @laune it's just dummy code for a simplified version of my code

Comment: @John, why do you even need an enum? Java 6? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @SlightlyCuban docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: How do you convert a list of strings into a list of enums? Well, first of all, how do you convert a string into an enum? Once you have that (just search, on here or google), do that for each item in the list.

Comment: @DavidConrad Why do you have to be rude instead of helpful? I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: You asked a question. I answered it. I'm sorry if that seems rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
List<Number> listofNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
for( String s: listOfStrings ){
    try {
        Number number = Enum.valueOf( Number.class, s );
        // or shorter:  Number.valueOf( s );     
        listOfNumbers.add( number );
    } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ){
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Number.valueOf`. Why use the `Enum` version?

Comment: @SlightlyCuban Basically it's the same thing, but yes, you're right: it's shorter.